# How to know which button is clicked in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way to know which button is clicked using PHP. I am new to this "world" so it is kind of difficult for me to figure it out by myself.

So what basically i am doing is a website that will control an Arduino (iot) and i am giving the admin the privileges to give access to his house to who ever he wants and also deletes who ever he wants. i am doing this with the help with a database of course (mysql).
This is how it looks :
[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuU97.png)

When the admin fill the inputs and submit it will add a person to database then display it with a delete button. This is the code i m using for the button :

```
  <form method="post" action="addAdmin.php">
      <button type="submit" style="background:none; border:0; box-shadow: none; border-radius: 0px; cursor: pointer; color: red;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
  </form>
```

I want to know how i can know which user did the admin choose to delete but i can not figure it out.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If your question has been answered, accepting an answer with the check mark can help others find an answer as well as helping direct community efforts. If your question was not answered, please advise what is missing or update your question with more information.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is supply information other than just having the delete button.
Currently the only thing you are doing is loading the `addAdmin` script, but you are passing zero information.

The simplest way to do this would be to add a hidden input with a key of the current user that the button is supposed to be for, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="addAdmin.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?= $userID ?>" />
    <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</form>
```

Then in the `addAdmin` script you can check the `$_POST` array for the `user` key, and work from there.

Comment: That s what i was thinking of but how will the input hidden impact the button ? how can i know the button. Cause when i click the button i go to the delete script. Is there like a way to create the same button but with different value ? and every time the button is clicked i pass the value to the script and from there i look on the table for it.

Comment: Because the button is not just a button, it is a button submitting a form, you just currently have nothing in that form. If you include a different hidden input field for each button (which is also a whole form), then when you load the `addAdmin` script it will include that additional data in the `$_POST` variable that you can then check.

Comment: I am not really getting it because i have only one form ( button ) and it is kind of duplicated each time an admin is added

Comment: @MikeKihl You have to share exactly what you mean by "duplicated" by adding it to your question. Currently that is far too vague for us to help with.

Answer (score -1):

You can give the button the `name` attribute.

```html
<form method="post" action="addAdmin.php">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" style="background:none; border:0; box-shadow: none; border-radius: 0px; cursor: pointer; color: red;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved by utilizing name/value attributes of button tag. 
This is a HTML chunk:

```
<form action="/delete.php" method="post">
  <button name="delete_id" type="submit" value="1">User 1</button>
</form>
...
<form action="/delete.php" method="post">
  <button name="delete_id" type="submit" value="2">User 2</button>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$deleteId = $_POST['delete_id'];
// call sql query and pass $deleteId
?>
```

Comment: on my code i am having only one button but it is "duplicated".

Comment: @MikeKihl the answer is suggesting you add the name and value attributes to the button, not copy both snippets of HTML. If this is not what happened, please comment more precisely what you mean by duplicated.